# Why the merge operator is not returning the first observable that it receives?

Tags: java, testing, rx-java2

My understanding is that I can use the merge operator with 2 other Observables followed by the firstOrError operator to return the first Observable that returns a result.

I'm trying to run a test case but it doesn't seem to do what I thought it would do, so not sure if there's an issue with my test or I'm using the operators incorrectly, I appreciate if anyone could help me with that. If anyone know of a better way to achieve the same results that would be great too.

Here's my test case:

```
@Test
public void testMergeOperator() {
    TestObserver<String> observer = new TestObserver<>();

    Observable<String> foo = Observable.just("FOO");
    Observable<String> bar = Observable.timer(2, SECONDS).just("BAR");

    foo.publish(first -> Observable.merge(first, bar.takeUntil(first))
            .firstOrError()
            .toObservable())
            .subscribe(observer);

    assertEquals(1, observer.valueCount());
    assertEquals("FOO", observer.values().get(0));
}
```

And I'm getting:

junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :FOO
Actual   :BAR

Comment: The `just` is a static factory method and a data source of its own  so you throw away the timer definition completely. You need an instance method to turn the timer signal into the BAR string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried using the map operator, which is an instance method over the Timer operator but got the same result. Could you maybe give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `just` with `map`:

```
@Test
public void testMergeOperator() {
    TestObserver<String> observer = new TestObserver<>();

    Observable<String> foo = Observable.just("FOO");
    Observable<String> bar = Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(v -> "BAR");

    foo.publish(first -> Observable.merge(first, bar.takeUntil(first))
            .firstOrError()
            .toObservable())
            .subscribe(observer);

    assertEquals(1, observer.valueCount());
    assertEquals("FOO", observer.values().get(0));
}
```

Comment: That's exacly what I did, still the same error. I don't get it. Using v2.1.9

Comment: If you copy-paste the code into a fresh unit test does it work for you?

Comment: Did you by any chance override the default `computation()` scheduler in `RxJavaPlugins`?

Comment: It worked! The issue was a TestRule overwriting the Schedules. Awesome, thanks!